# how to set print page setup in code using javascript

Tags: javascript, printing

I have 3 printers connected to one system and 1 is receipt printer among three of them.

If I change default printer as receipt printer printing going good. But if I change default printer to another printer then text font size either increases or decreases.

I want to know there is any code in JS to fix the settings of particular printer without effecting another printer page setup.

Comment: You could try changing the lay-out for printing using CSS: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in normal JS. You may be able to use [ScriptX](http://scriptx.meadroid.com/) to do what you need